# Fixed scrolling layout (not background fixed)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this sample layout http://codepen.io/joseluisq/pen/pvqEPL
and I need to do a layout fixed effect similar to http://www.soleilnoir.net/believein, **not background fixed**

In general, I tried to implement this effect with `window.scroll` event but the result is very bad when I'm scrolling faster, because the scroll position is missed.

I heard that the solution for this is simulate an `EnterFrame` function with `setTimeout`, but I don't understand how to implement it.

Any idea?

Comment: If you want to use a jquery plugin just google jquery Parallax Scrolling and choose a plugin.

Comment: Do you know about plugin for this?